# How do I deal with "not an answer" type .. answers ?

Tags: discussion, answers

So, what should be the protocol for posts in answers sections which are not answers (you know -  `OMGWTFBBQ I HAVE THIS PROBLEM` type posts)

- Flag for ♦ moderator attention ?
- Flag as offensive ?
- Flag as spam ?

I'm queasy about flagging for ♦ attention because.. these do not seem like things that require ♦ attention

Most of these posts are not offensive, maybe they fall into spam category ?

Thoughts ?

Comment: Maybe we need a new flag option for "noise" (because "spam" can cause a rep penalty, and we don't always want to penalise someone for simply misunderstanding the system)? If the new review page means the idea is to get greater community action against this problem, maybe there needs to be more functionality for us to do so (a noise flag, votes to remove answers, etc)?

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/72523/heuristics-for-detecting-a-bad-answer they are looking for ways to not even accept these 'answers' @Sathya

Comment: @Ivo yep this was in response to the `/review` route, but the linked Heuristics post was not yet up.

Comment: I'd also like to know what to do, there's one at http://superuser.com/questions/181490/how-can-i-get-vista-to-recognise-my-harddrive/223452#223452 but it's not spam/offensive and I on't know if it warrants a mod action (although that's how I've flagged it)

Comment: If it's not spam or offensive, flag as non-answer. @tom

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Flag for moderator attention. One of the moderators will spot the flag and nuke it.

Best ready to drop in that magic phrase when you make a note:

> Not an answer

Burn through your flags as much as you want for the daily limit.

Don't bother flagging multiple non-answers on the one question. The moderators will do a scan of the answer list to obliterate any other stragglers. Once per question will do fine and help you carry over another flag.

Come back again the next UTC day as you relive the magic and RSI cramping of hitting that key combination once more with feeling.

Comment: Alrighty. Will do.

Comment: Some good tips here; didn't think about the multiple answers per question note.