# Dealing with answers that simply discuss other answers to the same question

Tags: support, answers, delete

According to the [FAQ](https://superuser.com/faq#deletion), "Answers that are commentary on the question or other answers may be removed". Came across [this question](https://superuser.com/questions/189905/how-to-make-outlook-2010-minimize-when-i-try-to-close-it) with 8 non-deleted answers, 5 of which are fine. The remaining 3 though just seem to be discussing one of the 5.

The [main most highly voted answer](https://superuser.com/a/275244) (deservedly) is by Tim Eck who created the extremely useful KeepOutlookRunning add-in.

- [This answer](https://superuser.com/a/281565) by Jim M. simply discusses how to install the above plugin, without even mentioning it by name.
- [This answer](https://superuser.com/a/316202) by Yolgie does the same, and the installation instructions have long since been edited into Tim's answer (where they belong).
- Finally, [this answer](https://superuser.com/a/291720) by Joe is nothing more than a mere comment on Tim's answer.

IMO all three can be deleted, although not sure what's the best course of action for the last one i.e. Joe's "answer", because for some reason it was accepted by Tom. I've left a comment for him so perhaps better late than never he'll accept Tim's answer instead, but in any case I leave it to the mods to decide what should be done. (It was easier to post here rather than flag multiple answers and write long comments for each one.)

Comment: In general, all of these are not obviously not answers. One (Jim M.) is rather unspecific and could refer to the question, the others are essentially duplicate answers;  It's probably just that nobody's flagged them so far.

Comment: @DanielBeck: No, if you read carefully, when Jim says it works for him and talks about the VC++ redistributable being required, he's clearly discussing Tim's add-in.

Comment: Thanks, noticed that after reading it for the third time as well.

Comment: Your title is a bit misleading.  This is more a question about a specific question/case rather then in general.  In general ['nuking through flags'](http://meta.superuser.com/q/1778/47225) is the correct approach

Comment: @KronoS: Yeah, I guess it is about a specific question more than being a generic thread. That's one of the reasons I didn't tag this "Discussion". Also, as I clearly mentioned in my last sentence, this thread was meant for the mods in lieu of flagging thrice and typing up long comments each time (since TBH I find it better now to leave a comment when I flag rather than simply selecting the NAA option). Thanks for the link BTW.

Comment: @DanielBeck: Doh! I just flagged one of the non-answers, but linked to the wrong meta post! I had the one KronoS linked to above open and copy-pasted its URL instead. Tried to re-flag with proper link but seems that's not allowed since my second flag never showed up in my list. Sorry for the mixup.

Comment: I followed up on your flags and converted the previously accepted answer to a comment. Good I checked here, because your message was a little confusing :)

Comment: @slhck: Thanks a lot, really appreciate your detective work. :) I actually thought that since Daniel had taken cognisance of this post he'd have gotten rid of them already, but KronoS' comment made me think a flag might be required after all. So did I *have* to flag or could you guys have taken care of this after just reading this post? Is a flag absolutely required to initiate action?

Comment: Flags are not always necessary, but they won't hurt, especially when you link to a Meta post. Moderators can be quite busy and forget to follow up on things... it happens :)

Comment: @Karan The comment and link was more for other visitors to the question who aren't as knowledgeable.  I assumed you knew what you were doing, and figured you were talking to the mods. ;)

Comment: @slhck: Cool, good to know about the flags, and yeah, I know from experience that moderating can be a tiring and often thankless job. So, status-completed I guess?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As Daniel Beck mentioned, those kind of slipped through the cracks. Jim and Yolgie's answers were deleted, and the formerly accepted answer was converted to a comment on Tim's answer.

I think in such a complicated case going to Meta was the best choice.

Thanks for explaining the situation and bringing it to our attention.